# How to scroll to id after clicking on the internal Link in Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am building a blog and after clicking on Link linking to an article I want the new page to be scrolled on the Title of the article.

I have tried to use `` <Link to={`/${node.slug}#blog-title`}>{node.title}</Link> ``
but it doesn't scroll to title, it scrolls back to top of the page.

I have tried to use window.scrollTo(document.getElementById('blog-title); in componentDidMount but it looks like it's not renered until then and it still goes to top. If I use setTimeout it only scrolls to top to straight away scroll to the correct id.

index.js

```
return (
  <article className="blog-listing" key={node.slug}>
    <div className="entry-meta-content">
      <h2 className="entry-title">
        <Link to={`/${node.slug}`}>{node.title}</Link>
      </h2>
      <span className="entry-meta">
        Created on {node.publishDate} By {node.author.name}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div className="entry-media">
      <Img fluid={node.heroImage.fluid} backgroundColor="#f4f8fb" />
    </div>
    <div className="entry-content-bottom">
      <p className="entry-content">{node.body.childMarkdownRemark.excerpt}</p>
      <Link to={`/${node.slug}`} className="entry-read-more">
        <span />
        Read More
      </Link>
    </div>
  </article>
);
```

blog-post.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import Template from '../components/layout';

class BlogPostTemplate extends Component {
  render() {
    const post = get(this, 'props.data.contentfulBlogPost');
    return (
      <Template>
        <Helmet title={`${post.title}`} id="blog-title" />
        <div className="inner-blog-post">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <div className="entry-media">
                  <Img fluid={post.heroImage.fluid} backgroundColor="#f4f8fb" />
                </div>
                <h1 className="section-headline"> {post.title} </h1>
                <p> {post.publishDate} </p>
                <div
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: post.body.childMarkdownRemark.html
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Template>
    );
  }
}

export default BlogPostTemplate;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query blogPostQuery($slug: String) {
    contentfulBlogPost(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      body {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
      heroImage {
        file {
          url
        }
        fluid(maxWidth: 1800) {
          ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. Looks like an "interesting" problem :/
Have you had a look at the raw html/js that results from your template? What does `/${node.slug}#blog-title` resolve to? what is in the generated html for your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `blogpost.js`, you're attaching an id to the `<Helmet>` tag, which doesn't generate any content in the body. Perhaps you should attach it to the title in the body instead?

```
      ...
      <Template>
 -      <Helmet title={`${post.title}`} id="blog-title" />
 +      <Helmet title={`${post.title}`} />
        <div className="inner-blog-post">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <div className="entry-media">
                  <Img fluid={post.heroImage.fluid} backgroundColor="#f4f8fb" />
                </div>
 -              <h1 className="section-headline"> {post.title} </h1>
 +              <h1 id="blog-title" className="section-headline"> {post.title} </h1>
      ...
```